# Espresso test permission denied execute shell command "geo fix.."

Tags: android, android-espresso

Looking for a solution to this permission issue running an espresso test which is sending in "geo fix" commands.

```
@Test
public void test_geofix() { 
   // ...throws exception
   InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().
       getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("geo fix -70 40 3");
}
```

throws this exception (appearing in log but is caught by UIAutomation):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running shell command
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection$1.run(UiAutomationConnection.java:300)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "geo": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:983)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:691)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:524)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:421)
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection$1.run(UiAutomationConnection.java:286)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:128)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:964)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:691) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:524) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:421) 
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection$1.run(UiAutomationConnection.java:286)
```

Tried adding ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission to App-under-test (in debug manifest) but that produced a "permission only granted to system apps".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get UIDevice and then `device.executeShellCommand("command here")`